# Icons not visible after compilation

Tags: java, intellij-idea, joptionpane, imageicon

ok i am a new one here and tried to write an awesome program:

```
package f;

import javax.swing.*;

public class dasMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("pics/daFaq.png");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, img, "u r heck", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

the thing is that if I run the program from Intellij Idea, then everything works fine, but after compilation the picture disappears

here are the source files of the project:
https://i.ibb.co/Njc8jYp/screen.png

i want to run this awesome code with pictures on other computers, but i only know this way and it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably do not know where your program expects the picture to be. If you modify your code slightly, this information would be evident. Make use of

- [ImageIcon(URL)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.net.URL))
- [File.toURI()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#toURI())
- [URI.toURL()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URI.html#toURL())

With that your code can look like this:

```
package f;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.File;

public class dasMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File png = new File("pics/daFaq.png");
        System.out.println("Loading image from " + png.getAbsolutePath());
        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(png.toURI().toURL());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, img, "u r heck", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Also I am pretty sure you intend to ship the png together with your code, so you better load it as a resource from the classpath. Here is an  [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72739843/4222206).

I also investigated a bit why you would not see any error message or exception. This is documented in [ImageIcon](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html). So you might want to verify the image was loaded using [getImageLoadStatus()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#getImageLoadStatus()).

Answer (score 0):

If you access the resource with the path like `pics/file_name.png`, then the `pics` - is the **package name**. And it must be located in the directory, **marked as resource type**. For example, create the directory, named `resources` in your project root, mark this directory as **resource** type, and move the `pics` there:

[image]

P. S. I would advise to use Maven or Gradle build system for managing project builds. As it is commonly accepted build management systems for the JVM projects. IDE **New Project Wizard** has the option to create Maven or Gradle based projects.

Comment: Be aware the code in the question does not load from he classpath. Therefore pics is not a package but just a directory.